# A question on tabs

Tags: html, css, django, templates, tabs

I want to introduce tabs into my Django web application. I going to see if I could just doo it all in css + html. Now while practising with tabs from http://www.htmldog.com/articles/tabs/, this is what I have done so far.

**page1.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01// EN" >
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="base.css" />
</head>
<base>
<div id="header"> 

<h1>Tabs</h1>
<ul>
    <li id="selected"><a href="page1.html">This</a></li>
    <li><a href="page2.html">That</a></li>
    <li><a href="page3.htm">The Other</a></li>
    <li><a href="page4.htm">Banana</a></li>
</ul>

</div>


</base>
</html>
```

**page2.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01// EN" >
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="base.css" />
</head>
<base>

 <div id="header"> 

<h1>Tabs</h1>
<ul>
    <li><a href="page1.html">This</a></li>
    <li id="selected"><a href="page2.html">That</a></li>
    <li><a href="page3.htm">The Other</a></li>
    <li><a href="page4.htm">Banana</a></li>
</ul>

</div>


</base>
</html>
```

Now page1.html, and page2.html are almost the same. The only thing that is different,
`id="selected"` part just to indicate which tab has been selected. So what I want to do is remove any code that is redundant. For start, I wonder if it even possible I could even cut it to one `index.html` page  as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have one page with two different states using CSS + HTML only. Setting of `id="selected"` needs to result from come code somewhere, either on the server, or on the client.

You can use a URL hash to set the tab state using JavaScript. For example:

```
mypage.html#tab1
```

You can have JavaScript look at the value of `document.location.hash` and set `selected` on the appropriate tab.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't try to reinvent the wheel. Check out jQuery UI. Has tabs built in. http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/